# Only Banach Spaces can be reflexive

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $E$ be a normed space over $\mathbb K$. For each $x \in E$, let $x̂ : E^* \to \mathbb K$ be defined by $x̂ (l) = l(x)$, $l \in E^*$. Then the map $\Lambda_E: E \to (E^*)^*, \Lambda_E(x) = x̂ $ is an isometric linear operator. $E$ is called $reflexive$ if $\Lambda_E(x)$ is surjective.

Why can only Banach spaces be reflexive?

Comment: You can prove that the map $\Lambda_E$ is an isometry.

Comment: What do you know about the dual of a normed space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dual space of any Normed vector space is complete and therefore $(E^*)^*$ is a Banach space. In the case that the isometric map is surjective it therefore transfers the completeness to the space $E$.

Comment: Thanks. I see why it works when we have a surjective isometric map. Is it already sufficient if there exists a bounded + linear isomorphism from one normed space into another to transfer completeness?

Comment: That depends on what an isomorphism defines for you. The definitions i know, require that the inverse operator is bounded. But i have seen one where they do not require that. It does not suffice to have a bijective bounded linear Operator. The inverse must be bounded (by the inverse map theorem). An example: $X=(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and $Y=(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$. Then the Operator $T \colon X \to Y, f \mapsto f$ is clearly linear bijective and bounded. But $Y$ is not banach and the inverse operator is not bounded ($f_n = t^n$ leads to $\|f_n\|_1 = \frac{1}{n+1}$ but $\|f_n\|_\infty = 1$).